# How to get the html code modified client side that was generated from the server side?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, htmlgenericcontrol

I created a list with jquery sortable + C#, that the user (client) can order:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    HtmlGenericControl ul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
    ul.ID = "ID";
    ul.ClientIdMode = Static;
    HtmlGenericControl li_1 = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
    li_1.ID = "segment";
    li_1.InnerText = "server 1";
    li_1.ClientIdMode = Static;
    HtmlGenericControl li_2 = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
    li_2.ID = "page";
    li_2.InnerText = "server 1";
    li_2.ClientIdMode = Static;
    ul.Controls.Add(li_1);
    ul.Controls.Add(li_2);
    static.Controls.Add(ul);
}
```

Server Generate:

```
<div id="static" runat="server">
<ul id="ID">
    <li id="segment">server 1</li>
    <li id="page">server 2</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Client Generate (modified):

```
<div id="static" runat="server">
<ul id="ID">
    <li id="page">client 1</li>
    <li id="segment">client 2</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Event Save:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlGenericControl ul = Libreria.Global.FindControlRecursivo(this, "ID") as HtmlGenericControl;
    foreach(HtmlGenericControl li in ul.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>())
    {
        // Always get html generated by server, first "segment" element and after "page" element
    }
}
```

If every time I generate dynamic code on every postback I always get the code that the server generates, if valid then the lists are empty postback. =(

How do I get the html code modified client side that was generated from the server side?

**Update:**
other option is using **WebMethods**
with javascript send the html:

```
document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML;
```

I Can´t process the elements is a simple string

```
HtmlGenericControl ul = new HtmlGenericControl();
ul.InnerHtml = stringHtml;
foreach(HtmlGenericControl li in ul.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>())
{
    // any element
}
```

Comment: How are you modifying the content on the client?

Comment: JQuery Sortable http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Answer (score 0):

more read about. what is server control.
asp.net manage their control in viewstate and here in your scenario you are creating control on client side using jquery and send it's inner Html as string to the server side.. which is treated as string on server side is true.

you can do one thing to maintain this. just use ajax and add item to your "static" div on server side and it will be render on client side. cause of partial post back it won't take time. and look like your are creating it client side.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with an object in javascript, the user changes the elements (li) and to do click save final order of the elements and sends calling one webmethod working with this array type object